# How can I solve the 2D Laplace equation with Neumann boundary conditions?

Tags: differential-equations, syntax

I would like to solve the following boundary value problem for $u(x,y)$:

#### PDE

$\quad \quad \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0$

#### Domain

$\quad \quad 0 \le x \le L$

$\quad \quad 0 \le y \le H$

#### Boundary conditions

$\quad \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \big|_{x=0} =\; B$

$\quad \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \big|_{x=L} =\; B$

$\quad \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \big|_{y=0} =\; 0$

$\quad \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \big|_{y=H} =\; 0$

$B$ is a constant.

FYI: Unless I'm mistaken, the general solution for this boundary value problem (BVP) takes the form:

\begin{equation}
    u(x,y) = - \sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n \left( \frac{B}{\lambda_n}\right) \left( \frac{\sinh \left(\frac{\lambda_n L}{2}\right)}{\sinh \left(\lambda_n L\right)}\right) \cos\left( \lambda_n y \right) \left[ 2 \sinh\left(\frac{\lambda_n L}{4}\right) e^{\lambda_n\left(\frac{L}{4} + x\right)} + e^{\lambda_n\left(\frac{L}{2} + x\right)} \right],
\end{equation}

where $\lambda_n \equiv \frac{n \pi}{H}$, and $C_n$ are undetermined real coefficients.

I can solve this by hand easily enough via separation of variables, but I suspect *Mathematica* ought to be able to solve this.

#### Code

```
(* Start with a clean kernel *)
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Remove["Global`*"];

(* The PDE *)
LaplaceEqn = D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0;

(*The Boundary Conditions*)
minXBC = Derivative[1, 0][u][0, y] == b;
maxXBC = Derivative[1, 0][u][L, y] == b;
minYBC = Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 0;
maxYBC = Derivative[0, 1][u][x, H] == 0;

soln = DSolve[{LaplaceEqn, minXBC, maxXBC, minYBC, maxYBC}, u, {x, y}]
```

Unfortunately, that code produces the following output (*Mathematica 10*):

> ```
>  DSolve[
>     {(u^(0,2))[x,y]+(u^(2,0))[x,y] == 0,
>      (u^(1,0))[0,y] == b, (u^(1,0))[L,y] == b, 
>      (u^(0,1))[x,0] == 0, (u^(0,1))[x,H] == 0},
>     u, {x, y}]
> ```

This kind of PDE is supposedly solveable by *Mathematica*, according to the documentation of [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)

I can invoke DSolve in the following way...

```
soln = DSolve[LaplaceEqn, u, {x,y}]
```

...but it gives useless results:

```
{{u -> Function[{x, y}, C[1][I x  y] + C[2][-I x + y]]}}
```

I understand that that might mean something to somebody, but I want a real-valued solution in closed-form (a series expansion with undetermined weights is okay).

What am I doing wrong? How can *Mathematica* solve this analytically in a way that takes these boundary conditions into account?

Comment: @march I'm guessing he copied that from the output - so that wasn't an actual error in the input...

Comment: The general result for `DSolve[LaplaceEqn,u,{x,y}]` is indeed correct, because any arbitrary (holomorphic) functions of $x\pm i y$ satisfy the equation. But with boundary conditions, there is no closed form solution, and the series solution is not what you'll get unless you specifically ask for an expansion in terms of eigenfunctions (but that has to be put in by hand).

Comment: Is your goal to obtain specifically the series form as you wrote it, and determine the coefficients? Or do you want a purely numerical solution?

Comment: @Jens. But wouldn't that paste with `Superscript` boxes and such? In any case, it seems like you're right, since per your comment, it is returning a correct solution. I'm guessing DSolve would return something like `C[1][x - v*t] + C[2][x + v*t]` for the wave equation.

Comment: @march That's right, the two are related by $y = i t$. But of course that makes a big difference for the kind of boundary conditions we can use.

Comment: FYI, your original code had all of the boundary derivatives equal to zero (in which case the only solution is a constant.)  I've modified the code to match the equations.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert It looks like your edit of the code was the opposite of what you wanted. Anyway, to answer the question we need to know if the goal is to obtain the (exact but infinite) expansion or a numerical result.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Sorry, looks like m_goldberg reverted your change by accident. I think I'll edit the question myself to fix it.

Comment: I copied the input and output "as plain text".

Comment: @Jens: I do not want a numeric result (e.g. via `NDSolve`, which would be easier), but rather an exact, analytic form. I'm not sure if the series expansion is the best way to go, seeing as how there's an infinite number of undetermined coefficients. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure that the boundary conditions are simply inconsistent so that there is no solution at all unless `b = 0`. The reason is that the functions $\cos(n\pi y/H)$ cannot be superimposed to form a constant on the interval $[0,H]$, only on $[0,H/2]$.

Comment: @Jens: The boundary conditions are consistent with the PDE. This can be shown by its consistency condition, or proved via the 2D divergence theorem, if you'd prefer. The functions $\cos(n \pi y/H)$ *can* be superimposed to a constant, if only for the trivial $n=0$ case (i.e. $C_{n \neq 0}=0$).

Comment: What made this question off-topic? The answer is not easily found in the documentation: I've spent 3-5 hours searching the official documentation and found that Wolfram claims Mathematica can solve it but gives no 2D example with boundary conditions. If there is a typo in my question, tell me and I'll fix it. If there is a problem with my syntax, write an answer about it, because that is what I am asking. While my specific BVP might not help future visitors, I expect the answer to be helpful because the question has not been asked here yet and is not covered by the documentation.

Comment: @Jens: You mentioned that Mathematica can handle boundary conditions if you explicitly ask for an eigenvalue expansion. If that's what we need to do to solve this class of problems in Mathematica, describe that method in an answer.

Comment: The $n=0$ term is the only one consistent with a constant $x$ derivative at $x=0,L$, but for that term everything is constant and there can be no *nonzero* derivative at any boundary. I could illustrate the general method, but only for an example that is actually solvable. You would have to edit the question to change the boundary conditions. `DSolve` is only rarely able to solve PDEs with boundary-conditions -  the numerical solvers are able to do that better.

Comment: @Jens: My analytic answer may have a mistake. I know for a fact that the boundary value problem is well-posed. I've derived it several times: the domain volume integral of the Laplacian equals the domain surface integral of the outward normal derivatives, meaning it is consistent and that a solution exists.